# Does advanced rest client support client ssl certificates?

Tags: ssl-certificate, advanced-rest-client

Need to test an ssl api that requires a client cert. Is there a way to do that with [advanced rest client](https://install.advancedrestclient.com/) ?

Comment: why don't u use Postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advanced REST Client at the moment do not support client certificates. It is planned feature though: https://github.com/advanced-rest-client/arc-electron/issues/29